# how to shuffle numbers with textarea in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, shuffle

If I put numbers into a textarea like so:

```
418484
418485
418486
```

I want them to get shuffled, and I want an output like this:

```
418485
418484
418486
```

I don't want the values changed - I just want some JavaScript or jQuery that will shuffle these numbers and give me the result in my web page.

Comment: Please show us your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this great shuffle function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/10221765):

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

From there, you can simply get the value of the `<textarea>`'s input, and split it based on linebreaks:

```
var numbers = document.getElementById("numberInput").value.split("\n");
```

Or if you prefer spaces:

```
var numbers = document.getElementById("numberInput").value.split(" ");
```

Then, just pass it into the function:

```
var shuffledNumbers = shuffle(numbers);
```

And show them on the page by iterating over them and writing them to the document:

```
shuffledNumbers.forEach(function(currentNumber) {
    document.write(currentNumber + "<br />");
})
```

And there you go!

## EDIT:

If you want to display the shuffled numbers in another `<textarea>` instead:

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");
shuffledNumbers.forEach(function(currentNumber) {
    output.innerHTML += currentNumber + "\n";
})
```

Comment: but i need to show shuffled numbers in another textarea when i try that  the function not working

Comment: So you want to show the shuffled numbers in another text area? OK, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @MahmoudAdelMansour I've edited my answer, does it fix your problem?

Comment: in tow ways ( write ) or ( innerHTML) some times working and now i have get no thing white page or empty output text area

Comment: when i insert more than 100 number

Comment: That's odd - it works perfectly fine for me. Maybe it's having trouble rendering or processing?